# How to find and add a public key to my gpg keyring from command line using email address?

Tags: gpg

I have my public key published on keyservers and now I'm on a new computer and I want to import it using the `gpg` command line tool. I know I can download the public key and import it using `gpg --import public.key.file`, however I want to know whether one can do it directly in command line using the email address.

If this is not possible what is the reason for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GnuPG has the `--search`, `--recv-keys` and `--send-keys` commands for interaction with key servers.

OpenPGP key servers don't validate anything, they just distribute keys. This means, anyone can upload keys with arbitrary user IDs -- just search the key server network for [`president@whitehouse.gov`](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=president%40whitehouse.gov&op=vindex) -- I woulnd't expect any of those to belong to a (former or current) president of the United States.

For this reason, you can use `gpg --recv-keys` only with a key ID, not a user ID ([and be aware short key IDs aren't any better!](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74009/19837)). There is `gpg --search`, though, which allows to (interactively) search the key servers on the command line -- but be aware about the security issues it implies, and make sure to validate the key after downloading (for example, by comparing the fingerprint or at least long key ID).